# searching a directory for a particular extension and move that value into a variable in c

Tags: c

Need help with a C program to search for file with any extension (e.g. .xyz) and store the name of the file into a variable.

I can search a directory for the file name but not able to move it into a variable getting a segment error

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>


#if (defined( __STDC__) || defined(_WINDOWS)) && !defined(apollo)
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
//Fuction starting
char getfeature(char *dir)
{
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *entry;
regex_t regex;
int reti;
char msgbuf[100];
char feature;

/* Compile regular expression */
 reti = regcomp(&regex, ".xyz$", 0);

        if( reti )
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
            exit(1);
        }


if((dp = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"cannot open directory: %s\n", dir);
    return;
}
while((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
    reti = regexec(&regex, entry->d_name, 0, NULL, 0);
    if( !reti ){
    printf("this is match file %s\n", entry->d_name);
    var1 = entry->d_name;
    printf("This is feature file name %s", var1 );
    return var1;
       }
    else printf("file not found\n");
}
chdir("..");
closedir(dp);
}
```

Only this part is giving error

```
    var1 = entry->d_name;
    printf("This is feature file name %s", var1 );
    return var1;
```

Comment: Where and how did you define `var1`?

Comment: You have to return something from `getfeature` function if you don't do `exit(1);` because the type of its return value is not `void`.

Comment: If `var1` has `char` type, An invalid data (even not a pointer!) will be passed to the printf and it will cause runtime error.

Comment: If `var1` has `char*` type, I think it may be risky to return `entry->d_name` and copying it may be better. Moreover, You have forgotten `closedir(dp);` if a match file is found.

Comment: sorry just change char feature to char var1 and call the function
         char var1;

         void main()
        {
            getfeature(".");
        }
./test
file not found
this is match file aaa.xyz
Segmentation fault

Comment: MikeCAT thanks for looking into it i have tried all these but still getting the same Segmantation fault error

Answer (score 0):

`var1` is type `char`, so it cannot store address of string.
You will get runtime error if you pass it to `%s` in `printf`.

Please change the type of `var1` to `char*`.

Please note that there are more errors as I commented above.